# Is this function defined at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}$
Is it defined at $x=0$?
Does  lateral limits exist? The limits appears to exist almost always, but there is a 'infinitesimal probability' of $\sin{ \frac{1}{0}}$  be 0.
In general: can one mathematically consider that $\frac{0}{Not a Number}$ is defined as 0?

Comment: The function $\dfrac{x}{\sin\frac1x}$ diverges frequently often in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: "In general: can one mathematically consider that..." No. There are plenty of things that aren't numbers. In your case, you likely mean things like infinity. In a case like that, yes. A zero divided by an infinity is in general 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function isn't defined at $x=0$ and the denominator $\sin(1/x) = 0$ for $x = 1/k\pi$,  $k =\pm 1$, $\pm 2$... so the (lateral) limit does not exists.

Comment: I agree, and understand that from a point of view strictly mathematical, this is the correct answer.  But what if this function were coming from the real world?. Wouldn't we assume its continuity at $x=0$, considering that the 'probability' of other behavior at $x=0$ is negligible?. Doesn't  exist a "relaxed" or "probabilistic" concept of limit for these cases  in mathematics?

Comment: @Perspectiva8, for *any* value at $x=0$ tthe continuity is impossible,

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand exactly what you mean.  For _any_  value of  what?

Comment: @Perspectiva8, for any value of $f$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: Note also that l'Hôpital rule converges and says $\lim{f(x)}=0$

Comment: @Perspectiva8, You can't use L'Hôpital. $\sin(1/x)\not\to 0$.

Comment: For all successions $x_n$  in x that converge to 0 and such that $\lim{\sin(1/x_n)} \neq 0$, $\lim{f(x_n)}=0$ an there is not problem. On the other hand: for all successions $x_n$ in x that converge to 0 and such  $\lim{\sin(1/x_n)} = 0$ you can apply l'Hôpital and it gives also  $\lim{f(x_n)}=0$

Comment: If $\not\exists\lim f(x_n)$ for **some** $x_n\to 0$ then $\lim f(x)$ does **not** exists.

Answer (score 1):

It is not defined at $x=0$. The limit does not even exist near $0$. Indeed, let $x_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}$; then the $\sin$ term is $0$ so $f(x_n)$ is formally infinite.

However, if you were using the function $x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right)$, for instance, the limit as $x \to 0$ would exist and would be $0$. In that situation, we would say there was a removable singularity at $0$, and it would be entirely proper to assign the function the value $0$ at $0$.